# Showing Recent Issues ld: 84 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm dealing with this error It appears when I drag the FBSDKCoreKit and Bolts Framework, My app its working with the FacebookSDK framework, this is an old implementation as you should know, In my app I can share, Login, Register by Facebook the only thing is failing now is the login so I want the new implementation the new framework to do the login just the login but when I drag the necessary files This error appears, I was looking for a solution but I can't fix it yet, hope you can help me.

Showing Recent Issues
ld: 84 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

[image]

Comment: did you fix this?

Comment: Not yet, actually, I did other things, I think the only way to solve this issue is updating the Facebook SDK.

Comment: I think there might be a workaround using modules as the objects would be in different modules, but I dont think we can achieve this as the objects are contained in frameworks

Comment: Yes, I think the same, the problem with me is because I have many things implemented with the older FacebookSDK, so implemented them again will take many days, Finally I have to do that now or later but I`ll try for a solution in many ways and I can't. If You solve this after please let me know.

Comment: I had this problem with a different library, a few months ago.. had to do a really messy fix.. (could not make both libraries coexist)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **your old library and the new library create the same objects**, so when you try to compile the app it will display the duplicated objects error.
What you need to do is **remove the old library and work with the new one**.
Sorry but I've had this problem in the past and could not find a solution either. (about 10 hours spent looking for a workaround).

Comment: Want I don't want to do it's create again all the methods :( ok but I guess and you confirm me that, it's the only way, Thanks a lot